How to direct Java GC logs to Java Logger?
I have a Java server running on Google's Cloud-Run with garbage-collection logging enabled via
        "-Xlog:gc",
        "-Xlog:gc*=info,heap*=debug,safepoint=info",
        "-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary",
        "-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions",
        "-XX:+PrintNMTStatistics",

When the server is run locally or inside a local container, I can see the GC messages appear on the console.  But when I run it in Google's environment, those log messages do not go to the logging server.
My app does its logging via the slf4j library via something like this:
logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.mydomain")
logger.info("foo!")

The logback.xml configuration has this:
    <appender name="cloud" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        </encoder>
        <log>backend</log>
        <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

How can I get the GC log messages to take the same route as the app's internal logging?


How can I get the GC log messages to take the same route as the app's internal logging?

AFAIK you can't.  It is not supported.
GC logging is implemented in native code as part of the GC subsystem1.  It will be creating the log messages in C / C++ code using native buffers and writing them to native file descriptor.
To get the GC logging to use the app's logging framework (java.util.logging or a 3rd party logging facade or framework) the log events would need to be turned into Java objects; i.e. objects representing the events, format strings, logged values, and so on.  That's a big problem, because many GC log events happen at points there the all Java code is at a safe point and it is not possible to allocate and create any Java objects.
I imagine it would be possible to deal with that by (for example) buffering the GC logging events while Java object creation is not possible, but there is more.  Once Java objects have been created, they need to be processed by the (Java) logging framework.  But that can't happen until the GC allows normal Java code to run again.
In summary:

It is not supported.
It would be complicated to implement2.
GC log messages would only appear in the application logs after the GC had allowed normal Java code to resume.


Another answer suggested using stream redirection as an alternative.

Using System.setOut() or System.setErr() simply won't work.  GC logging doesn't go through a PrintStream ... let alone those associated with System.out and System.err.

You can direct GC logs to the file that your application logger is writing to; e.g. by using -Xlog:file=<path-to-common-log-file>.
However that's not equivalent to sending GC log events through the application's internal logging:

The GC log events would not be subject to the nice features that the logging framework provides; e.g. runtime configurable filtering and formatting.
If the application log events are sent to a centralized log (e.g. via a SocketAppender) the GC log events can't be sent there.
If the application and GC logging systems write to a common log file, you can't guarantee that the GC and normal log messages will be correctly interspersed and time ordered.  For example, you might get a GC log message in the middle of an application log message.  And things could get messed up if the application logger does log file rolling.



IMO, you are better off simply writing the GC logs to their own log file.  (In a K8s context where writing to a local disk file is problematic, you could use an in-memory tmpfs, and implement something else to stage the log entries to something outside of the pod.)

1 - See OpenJDK source on Github
2 - It would be up to the core OpenJDK team to do this work, starting with a JEP.  There are many other things that would / should take priority.  IMO.


If I redirect the logs to a file, is that file reopened every time a GC happens, or is the file held open and simply appended with every GC action?  (I'm thinking a background task could read and forward the log messages then delete the file.)

Here's one way it can be done.
I created a way to forward lines from a named pipe to the logging system.  I did it as an extensible base-class in case added functionality is needed in the future.  It's written in Kotlin but the same would work in Java.
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.File
import java.util.logging

open class ForwardLogfileLines(
    val logFilename: String,
    val logLevel: logging.Level,
    val logDone: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    private val job: Job

    init {
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                forwardLogLines()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logger.severe("${e}\n${e.stackTraceToString()}" }
            }
            forwardingComplete()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun forwardLogLines() {
        val file = File(logFilename)
        while (!file.exists()) delay(1000)
        logger.info("Monitoring ${logFilename}..." }

        file.inputStream().bufferedReader().use { reader ->
            reader.lineSequence().forEach { line ->
                forwardLogLine(line)
            }
        }
    }

    open suspend fun forwardingComplete() {
        logDone?.invoke()
    }

    open suspend fun forwardLogLine(line: String) {
        val level = getLogLevelFor(line)
        logger.log(level, line)
    }

    open suspend fun getLogLevelFor(line: String): logging.level {
        return logLevel
    }
}

Instantiating this with a named pipe ("path/to/gc.pipe") is all that is necessary to forward GC messages to the normal Java logging service.
Unfortunately, attempts to open a named pipe for writing will block if there is not yet any reader so there is a race-condition between the GC opening the pipe for write and the app opening the pipe for read after it starts.
I worked around this with two named pipes and a tiny shell function that is started in the background before launching the app.
#! /bin/sh

MEM=400M

copy_lines() {
  while true; do
    if read -r line; then
      echo "$line"
    fi
  done
}

cd /app
mkdir logs
mkfifo logs/gc.out
mkfifo logs/gc.pipe
copy_lines <logs/gc.out >logs/gc.pipe &

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms$MEM -Xmx$MEM -Xlog:gc:file=logs/gc.out -Xlog:gc*=info"
exec ./bin/myapp

